# unable to parse JSON data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to parse the data from JSON format, but i get first alert which is (insdie 1: object Object) and then i don't get the second alert. I am not sure what i did wrong.

**JS**

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/JsoupPrj/JasonGen?url="+url
                    ,function(data){
                var imageData = [];
                alert("inside 1 :" + data);
                $.each(data.items,function(i, item){
                    alert("insdie 2");
                    alert(item);
                    });
```

**JSON DATA**

```
{
  "title" : "x",
  "Description" : "rrr.",
  "images" : [ "http://1.jpg", "http://2.jpg", "http://3.jpg" ]
}
```

Comment: Is the page loaded from the same domain, i.e. `http://localhost:8080`? If not you won't be able to access it due to the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON data doesn't have a property called `items`, so `data.items` is undefined. Try `data.images` instead:

```
$.each(data.images,function(i, item){
```

Comment: Thanks, i just figure it out. How to get only images?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Within the `$.each()` loop `item` will be `"http://1.jpg"` on the first iteration, then `"http://2.jpg"`, etc. Unless you're asking how to populate your `imageData` variable with those values, in which case you can just say `imageData = data.images;`. But given `imageData` is a _local_ variable it's kind of redundant when you can just access `data.images` directly.